# Android SMS receiver not working

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I'm trying to write a simple application that attempts to receive SMS messages and handle them. I've followed several tutorials but I'm getting nowhere, when I send a SMS to the emulator, the Intent never seems to get fired.

Here is my intent:

```
package com.neocodenetworks.smsfwd;

import android.content.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.*;
import android.util.Log;

public class SmsReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private static final String TAG = "smsfwd";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());

        if (intent.getAction() == SMS_RECEIVED) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                }
                if (messages.length > -1) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody());
                    NetComm.SendMessage("me", messages[0].getOriginatingAddress(), messages[0].getMessageBody());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.neocodenetworks.smsfwd"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <receiver android:name=".SmsReciever">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECIEVED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="6" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

I'd really appreciate some guidance with what's going wrong. I'm just getting into Android development but I think I have my head wrapped around (most of) it. While monitoring the emulator's logcat, the log events never come up, and debugging breakpoints are never hit, so I have a feeling it's somewhere in my intent filter.

I'm running this on Android 2.0.1.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Comment: For more suggestions into why an SMS broadcast received isn't being fired, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to [Samuh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1944935/50776) (you need to do an object comparison on the action string, or just do no comparison), in your manifest file you have misspelled `SMS_RECEIVED`.

Comment: In case you are using Eclipse with ADT, you can avoid such errors by adding permissions using the Permission Tab that the Manifest Editor provides rather than typing them yourself.

Comment: While Samuh is correct, the fact I had misspelled it was what was stopping it from working. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I think your manifest looks okay; the problem is with the line:

```
if (intent.getAction() == SMS_RECEIVED) {
```

I think it should be: `intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)`

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 1):

The action name seems to require a capital "T" in "Telephony.

`android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`

Answer (score 1):

For `String` variables you should not compare with `==` symbol, you should compare with `equals()` method

this is wrong

```
intent.getAction() == SMS_RECEIVED)
```

this is right

```
intent.getAction().equals (SMS_RECEIVED))
```