# Select first SMS on Android database inbox

Tags: android, sms

I am desperate to find the solution so I ask for help!
I am a new french programmer. My objective is to create a widget able to show SMS.
My problem is that I don't know how create a cursor which select the first SMS in content://sms/inbox
Excuse my bad English, I hope you will able to understand my wich.
Thank you for your answer.
this is my code:

```
package sfeir.monwidget;
import android.R.string;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;   


public class MonWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

 public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
     Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    // returns all the results.
    Cursor c= getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null,null); 
    // called by the Activity.
    startManagingCursor(c);
    String body = null;
    String number = null;

    if(c.moveToFirst()) { // move cursor to first row
       // retrieves the body and number of the SMS
       body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
       number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
    }

    // when your done, close the cursor.
    c.close(); 
 RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
         R.layout.widget_layout);


 updateViews.setTextColor(R.id.text, 0xFF000000);
 updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text, (CharSequence) body);

 ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MonWidget.class);
 appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
 }
```

}

Comment: Your english isn't too bad, no need to be excused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to set specific permissions (read below for the link) but here is example of the code to use a `Cursor` to retrieve the first SMS message.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
// returns all the results from the given Context
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null,null); 

String body = null;
String number = null;

if(c.moveToFirst()) { // move cursor to first row
   // retrieves the body and number of the SMS
   body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
   number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
}

// when your done, close the cursor.
c.close();
```

I would recommend looking over [**FrontPage/Tutorials/SMS Messaging - Mobdev Wiki**](http://mobdev.olin.edu/mobdevwiki/FrontPage/Tutorials/SMS%20Messaging) it gives a good introductory on dealing with SMS handling on Android.

#### EDIT:

Those methods were not visible to your application because it was not extending to the `Activity` superclass. By default, when you develop an *application*, it inherits methods from that relationship. But you are not creating an application, per se, you are developing a widget.

Luckily, within the `onUpdate` method they pass in the current `Context` which is a super class for `Activity` so we can use the variable `context` to invoke `getContentResolver` (*see above in the code*)

I also removed [**`startManagingCursor`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startManagingCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29) method from the code, it is not completely necessary to have, it allows the Activity to handle the given `Cursor`'s lifecycle based on the Activity's lifecycle.

Let me know if theres any problems.

#### EDIT 2:

Inside your `AndroidManifest.xml` file you need to set the correct permissions to avoid any exceptions, add this line.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Thank's for this post! I wrote something quietly similar but now I understand what isn't correct. When I use this part of code I have the same problem as when I write mine, getContentResolver().query and startManagingCursor are not recognize by eclipse. I probably have forgoten to import something, I'll search in your tuto. Thank's a lot for your help!

Comment: In fact I don't understand what is the problem. This one come from those fonctions (getContentResolver().query and startManagingCursor) for which eclipse want to create a method. I already have import the classes concerned so do I forget something?

Comment: @Oliver, if you hover over where that code lies within Eclipse, when you right-click it will have a `import` option, like `import android.app.Activity` (where *`startManagingCursor`* lies) and `import android.content.ContentResolver` (where *`query`* lies)

Comment: I already have import those classes, perhaps is my extend false, it's named AppWidgetProvider. Is it an error to not create an another class for writing this fonction? Or should I create a class wich I import in my widget after?

Comment: You can extend to your own provider class (*AppWidgetProvider*) that contains retrieving SMS messages and inside of *AppWidgetProvider* you would need to import the necessary classes. I hope I am understanding your problem correctly.

Comment: @Olivier, there is a character limit for comments, edit your question above to include your code and I can take a look.

Comment: I import the necessary. I don't understand where is the problem

Comment: I can't find the reason why getContentResolver().query and startManagingCursor or not apply by beclipse...

Comment: It should work, refresh the project to see if that makes a different. Also try `import android.app.Activity`

Comment: I import more classes before, like import android.app.Activity and it make no difference. I tried again and still no difference. it's gonna make me crazy, I search on the web and can't find any solution..

Comment: Sometimes Eclipse may not recognize things until you hit refresh or `F5`, I hope thats what fixes it.

Comment: nothing happend, there seems to be an error. Per hap's may I use something else as a cursor bet it seems complicated...

Comment: `Cursor` is what you need, indeed. It only works on those two methods?

Comment: I am using android 2.1 SDK, the last publish by google including all library i need i think. I am going to sleep and think about a solution tomorow. It is my first widget, I will manage to create it! good night or good day wherever you are on earth!

Comment: Reason why those methods cannot be found is because they are implementing in the `Activity` class and when extending to `Activity` opposed to `AppWidgetManager` the error goes away. But, since you are dealing with a widget, opposed to an actual application there might be some caveats with that. I can look into it more.

Comment: Ok problem solved! It was such a problem of permission in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to listen for the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast intent and update your app widget in the broadcast receiver code. There is some information in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944102) regarding usage.

Comment: I allready have readen this topic but what I need is the first step of a bigger conception which is to acces with a cursor to sms/inbox. Later, I will develop some button to move the cursor and naturally to permit to see other sms. An easy fast navigation sms in a widget.

Comment: Ok problem solved! It was such a problem of permission in the manifest.