# Android - SMS Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, sms, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have been trying to get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944102/android-sms-receiver-not-working) program to work but so far having no luck. I cannot find where I am doing wrong. I'm not sure if there's something wrong with the code, or debugging.

I'm trying to be notified if a new SMS arrives.

Here is my program:

```
package Technicaljar.SMSBroadcastReceiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
        private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());

                if (intent.getAction() == SMS_RECEIVED) {
                    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                    if (bundle != null) {
                        Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                        final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        }
                        if (messages.length > -1) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody());
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
    }
```

And the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="Technicaljar.SMSBroadcastReceiver"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" >
        <receiver android:name=".SMSBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

I am sending SMS through Telnet, and I cannot see any Intent received messages in the logcat. Here is my logcat from the time of installation.

```
D/AndroidRuntime(  478): 
D/AndroidRuntime(  478): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(  478): CheckJNI is ON
D/AndroidRuntime(  478): --- registering native functions ---
D/AndroidRuntime(  478): Shutting down VM
D/dalvikvm(  478): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
I/AndroidRuntime(  478): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
D/Mms:app (  220): getSmsNewMessageNotificationInfo: count=14, first addr=12345, thread_id=4
D/dalvikvm(  151): GC_EXPLICIT freed 391 objects / 22552 bytes in 65ms
D/dalvikvm(  220): GC_EXPLICIT freed 926 objects / 44840 bytes in 73ms
```

So the SMS seems to be received by the emulator, but looks like the no intents are firing.
What am I doing wrong here? After installing, do I have to somehow 'start' this receiver?
Because when I install, I get

```
 [2010-11-07 21:24:41 - SMSBroadcastReceiver] No Launcher activity found!
[2010-11-07 21:24:41 - SMSBroadcastReceiver] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
```

So I'm wondering if something's wrong here.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-sms-mms-in-android

Comment: Are you not supposed to use `intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)` instead of `intent.getAction() == SMS_RECEIVED`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` has a capital `T`, and yours in the manifest does not.

Please bear in mind that this `Intent` action is not documented.

Comment: Thank you very much CommonsWare. That was the problem. It works fine now. Thank you. Also, can I ask why this Intent is not documented?

Comment: I didn't know it is not documented. I see lots of people using this intent I never thought it is not documented. Thank you for the info.

Comment: Is there a documented way to be notified if a short message arrives?

Comment: @Janusz: No, unfortunately. The fact that 99% of the code necessary to process incoming SMSes exists in the SDK, and this constant does not, would suggest that this constant is unlikely to change. However, I do not recall any official statements to that effect, and they certainly have not put it in the SDK despite ample opportunity to do so. Developers of SMS clients simply need to be aware of the issue and watch new Android releases like a hawk.

Comment: This intent may not be well documented but it is referenced in the public API documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html) and as such is 'fair game' for any Android dev to use.

Comment: @Phil: You are welcome to your opinion. Google may not share it. Some of these things they open up (e.g., `CalendarContract`). Some of these things they close down (e.g., Gmail content provider).

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm not disputing the fact that Google might choose to close down an API that is currently public. I'm just trying to draw a distinction between using a hidden API (such as the WiFi hotspot functionality) that is not included in the Android JavaDoc (and cannot be invoked except via reflection), and the public API for working with incoming SMS messages which is documented, and public.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you so much sir :) it's been four days and my broadcast receiver was not being invoked. the problem was smaller "t". the problem seems common one

Comment: @CommonsWare Spotting that 'T' was the Hawk Eye job! Kudos!

Comment: It's now documented in api 19 here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html#SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION

Comment: @CommonsWare BroadcastReceiver is calling 2 times for one message received.

Answer (score 18):

I tried your code and found it wasn't working.

I had to change

```
if (intent.getAction() == SMS_RECEIVED) {
```

to

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
```

Now it's working. It's just an issue with java checking equality.

Comment: FYI: its always better to call .equals(..) from a non-null string.     e.g - if (SMS_RECEIVED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

Answer (score 5):

Also note that the Hangouts application will currently block my BroadcastReceiver from receiving SMS messages. I had to disable SMS functionality in the Hangouts application (Settings->SMS->Turn on SMS), before my SMS BroadcastReceived started getting fired.

Edit: It appears as though some applications will abortBroadcast() on the intent which will prevent other applications from receiving the intent. The solution is to increase the `android:priority` attribute in the `intent-filter` tag:

```
<receiver android:name="com.company.application.SMSBroadcastReceiver" >
  <intent-filter android:priority="500">
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

See more details here: [Enabling SMS support in Hangouts 2.0 breaks the BroadcastReceiver of SMS_RECEIVED in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021492/enabling-sms-support-in-hangouts-2-0-breaks-the-broadcastreceiver-of-sms-receive?lq=1)

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.no/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html <-- Read the part about looking for changes made by other apps and also about the significance of priority "0"

Answer (score 3):

`intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)`

I have tried it out successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled across this today. For anyone coding an SMS receiver nowadays, use this code instead of the deprecated in OP:

```
SmsMessage[] msgs = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
SmsMessage smsMessage = msgs[0];
```

Comment: Do you need to enable runtime permissions for this?

Answer (score 2):

Your broadcast receiver must specify `android:exported="true"` to receive broadcasts created outside your own application. My broadcast receiver is defined in the manifest as follows:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".IncomingSmsBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

As noted below, exported="true" is the default, so you can omit this line. I've left it in so that the discussion comments make sense.

Comment: Nope. When a receiver has an intent filter it becomes exported automatically. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html#exported

Comment: Fair comment. I suspect this may have changed in a recent version of Android, my code was originally developed against Android 4.0. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For android 19+ you can get it in `Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION)`. There are more in the `Intent`s class that 're worth looking 
at

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered such issue recently. Though code was correct, I didn't turn on permissions in app settings. So, all permissions hasn't been set by default on emulators, so you should do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` is not correct because Telephony is a class and it should be capital as in `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`