# Android: Starting an application after recieving sms on a particular port

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am new to android, i want to as start an activity when i receive an sms on a particular port on android phone, my questions are:

Q1: how can i receive sms on a specific port?

Q2: how can i start an activity (UI) after receiving and parsing the sms?

Comment: Something like this should be what your'e looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver

Comment: Thank you Fredrick, but this only satisfies my "Q1" how can i launch an activity that contains a UI after receiving the sms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with an `IntentReceiver`.

Here's a good article http://www.anddev.org/recognize-react_on_incoming_sms-t295.html

Comment: Glad to help and best of luck with your app.