# State of telephone in Android

Tags: android

I'm looking for a sort of trigger in Android, that would let me perform a task whenever a sound is played, so for incoming calls, SMS and e-mail notifications. I did find something like this, but it's only for when the phone is called:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

What I want to achieve with this is sending a bluetooth signal to a bracelet, so it starts vibrating. This would be suited for the hearing impeared or people that work/live in a loud environment who don't carry their phone attached to their bodies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calls, SMSes and email are handled by different apps and they have different notifications. Besides calls, you can also get notifications for SMS but not for emails.

SMS broadcast is a private API, meaning that it is not officially supported and can change without notice: [Android - SMS Broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver)

Comment: But isn't there are a change of state when a sound is played?

Comment: Yes internal state of e.g gmail app, which then shows user notification with sound. There is no way to programmatically detect user notifications.