# Sender number and message body on Android

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I have a problem sending my message data to my server pc using Socket connection.

What I have done is established a TCP socket connection where PC is my server and android phone is my client. I am able to exchange data.

I am stuck -- I get a message on my android phone and I want to send to the PC server the sender number and message body using my already connected TCP connection to the PC server.

Answer (score 0):

Check how it's done in this question: [Android - SMS Broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver)

Basically, you'll need to give your app the required permissions, and then build and register a `BroadcastReceiver` object, that will get notified by the system when a message arrives.

Comment: I am able to receive SmS contents: sender number and message body on a Toast dat i used to display, but my main concern is how to send this to Server using TCP dat i have already established and i am also able to exchange the data but not getting to transfer this content over TCP.