# how can I handle SMS send/receive ?

Tags: java, android

I want to write method to send SMS on number and with text from edit text fields. After message is sent I want to receive some sound or something to alert me that SMS is received. How can I do that?
Thank you in advance,
Wolf.

Comment: when you have to get sound after sms sent or sms received ? make it clear in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This site seems to have a good write up of both: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

The important parts are this:

```
//---sends an SMS message to another device---
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{        
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, SMS.class), 0);                
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
}
```

And this answer has a simple broadcast receiver to get the text messages coming in: [Android - SMS Broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver)
Should look something like:

```
public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());

            if (intent.getAction() == SMS_RECEIVED) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                if (bundle != null) {
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                    final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                        messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                    }
                    if (messages.length > -1) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody());
                    }
                }
            }
       }
}
```