# SMS push-Notification

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, push-notification

I want to create an app which gives notification when sms is received or delivered using a brodcast receiver.How to do that?Thank You.

Comment: Is there a difference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver?

Answer (score 1):

try this
        public class smsActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
        protected static final String TAG = "PlayingAudio";



        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
             this.mContext = context;
             mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
             mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
            //---get the SMS message passed in---
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        

            if (bundle != null) 
            {
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
                for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);   
                    incomingnum=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    MsgBody=msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    //str += "SMS from " +incomingnum;                     
                    //str += " :";
                    str += MsgBody;
                   // str += "\n";        
                    System.out.println("Str is   "+str);
                } 
Notification notification = new Notification(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder,
                            "My Notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
                    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;*/ 

                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested in the emulator running an API 7 image.

Receiver class:

```
package add.yourpackage.here;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {
            StringBuilder smsSummary = new StringBuilder("SMS received from: ");

            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

                final String sender = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                final String message = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                smsSummary.append(sender);
                smsSummary.append("; ").append(message).append("\n");

                Log.d("SMS_RECEIVER", "Str is   " + smsSummary);
            }

            NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Notification notif = new Notification(
                    android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder, smsSummary,
                    System.currentTimeMillis());
            notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

            // The notification will be canceled when clicked by the user...

            notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            // ...but we still need to provide and intent; an empty one will
            // suffice. Alter for your own app's requirement.

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    notificationIntent, 0);
            notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, "SMS Notification",
                    "Another txt for you", pi);

            notifManager.notify(0, notif);
        }
    }
}
```

If you are running API 11+ you can use the [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) instead, but my phone is still on Gingerbread.

Manifest entry for the receiver. Your app will still need permissions defined to receive SMS messages, but I assume you've already done that:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".service.SmsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: That's okay this code will also work fine for API 8 :-) . I only tested on 7 as it is the lowest API I have installed and you didn't state one in the original question.