# Best approach to develop a GPS like application

Tags: android, view, imageview

I'm new to android and I'm starting to develop a GPS like application for android, the basic concept of the app is to show up a blueprint, and display on top of it pins with information related to the position on the blueprint and other settings.

An example of this would be taking a blueprint of an apartment which you can scale and pan, and on top of it place markers with information about each part of the apartment and obviously positioned in the right places like bathrooms, bedrooms, kitchen, etc.

My question is what is the best approach to develop this kind of functionality?

My first thoughts were to use a RelativeLayout as a container, an ImageView for the blueprint with zoom and pan capabilities and individual views for the pinning with the respective place for information positioned based on the zoom and pan of the image.

Then I kept digging and saw the 2d Graphics option but I don't really know how to implemented for this.

I'll appreciate if anyone can send me in the right direction and if is possible some examples as well.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MapView` with an `ItemizedOverlay` to display the markers. [Here's a step-by-step answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216151/updating-google-maps-marker-from-a-broadcast-sms-receiver/10216546#10216546) how to accomplish this (See *Item B* of the answer).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I that is not what i'm looking for.
Here is an example of what I'm looking: Let's take the blueprint of an apartment, that would be the map, and there will be markers positioned and with information about toilets, bedrooms,  etc.

Comment: Is your goal to GPS-enable this app, or is it simply a way to annotate  a scrollable image?

Comment: It wont be GPS enable, you can see it as way to annotate a scrollable image