# How can i read sms using flex in android?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, sms

I'm developing application for android by using flex. That app should read sms from android and analise them. How can i read sms?  I've searched all over the Internet and couldn't find any articles which would be helpful.

Is there any way to do that instead of using native extention?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but unless sending sms is part of the Air runtime (I don't think it is), you'll need find a way to call down into Java code in order to access the Android API for that functionality. If you're able to send Intents, that may be the cleanest way.

Comment: Yes. I am able to do that. It is doing by Native Extention which allows developer to insert Java or C code into his flex app. But i am looking for a way to do that by using only native flex functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Is there any way to do that instead of using native extention?"

Send sms - yes, but only by calling the device's native SMS client.

Receive/read incoming sms - no.

The Air mobile API includes features that allows you to *send* SMS messages by invoking the device's native SMS client. There are tutorials available online how to do this, for example [this](http://shaileshmakwana.blogspot.com/2010/12/adobe-air-2.html) one.

The Air mobile API does not includes methods that allow you to *read* incoming SMS messages. To implement this on an Android device you would have to write your own Native Extension.[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver) answer on SO explains how to set up a BroadcastReceiver using the Native Android SDK to listen for incoming SMS messages. If you need help on how to implement your own Native Extensions, the [Adobe Developer pages](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html) on the subject is a good start.

Comment: +1; although the claim that AIR allows you to send SMS Messages could be a bit misleading.  The URL syntax described in the post you link to will just open up the device's native SMS Messenger.  It does not perform any sending / manipulation of the SMS message.

Comment: Thank you. It's sad adobe doesn't maintain one of the basic feature of mobile devices. Btw do you know any custom native extention which allows you to operate with incoming messages?

Comment: @Kirill. No, unfortunately not. I did the usual search for it on google and github but no success. If you write one yourself, please share it with us:)