# android broadcast receiver android 4

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

because i cant post my question to this thread [Android - SMS Broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver?lq=1), i have to do it that way.

Does anybody know why this broadcast receiver isnt working on android 4? Ive tested it with 2.3.7 and it was working, but now with the android 4 update nothing happens :-/.