# Android Sms Broadcast Listener not working

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

Even the Log.d is not being called. Can't find the error. I have looked at [Android - SMS Broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver), [Android – Listen For Incoming SMS Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages). I have been looking for the solution for last 24 hours or so. Please see and tell where I am wrong.

No exceptions are thrown. `SmsListener` is in my package folder, where all other activities are placed.

**Update** added `android:enabled="true"` to receiver. Then also not worked.

I have in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<receiver android:name=".SmsListener" android:exported="false">
     <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
         <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

SmsListener.Java Code:

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG,
            "in Receiver. intent.getAction():" + intent.getAction());

    if (intent.getAction()
            .equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); // ---get the SMS message passed
                                            // in---
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String msg_from;
        if (bundle != null) {
            // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
            try {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                    NotifyMe(context, msg_from, msgBody);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
private void NotifyMe(Context context, String msg_from, String msgBody) {
     // do something
}
}
```

Comment: Did you tried set android:priority to 1000?

Comment: Trying Now. I thought assigning highest integer value will do.

Comment: @Andrey not working even then

Comment: Try to set it 999. Regarding to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#setPriority(int) 'Applications must use a value that is larger than SYSTEM_LOW_PRIORITY and smaller than SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY'. According http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY is 1000 (0x000003e8)

Comment: @Andrey not working. Rebuild the project, cleaned it. Uninstalled application from my phone and reinstalled. Not working yet

Comment: @Andrey thanks for help. it works after removing exported thing

Comment: you must be specify exported flag or otherwise it has to be true, otherwise messanger application will not be able to invoke it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is now solved. Modified receiver in manifest to

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsListener" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

It works for me. Hope someone gets benefited by this. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: my priority was 1000. Changed it to 999. This  worked. Don't know why but worked

Comment: Even, I modified from 1000 to 999, but no luck :(

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried to register receiver by the code? Below is for example how I did it in one of my projects, - it is working in my case.

**SMS Receiver class**

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Object[] pduArray = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pduArray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pduArray.length; i++) messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pduArray[i]);

        String SideNumber = messages[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
        long Timestamp = messages[0].getTimestampMillis();

        StringBuilder bt = new StringBuilder();
        for (SmsMessage message : messages) bt.append(message.getMessageBody());

        String Smsbody = bt.toString();
    }
}
```

**Service class - it registers broadcast receiver** This is just for example, you can register broadcast receiver in your Activity.

```
public class AService extends Service
{
  private SMSReceiver smsReceiver;
  final IntentFilter smsFilter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");

  @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
     smsFilter.setPriority(1000);
     this.smsReceiver = new SMSReceiver();
     this.registerReceiver(this.smsReceiver, smsFilter);
    }
}
```

**Part of AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<service android:name=".AService" android:exported="false"/>
```

Comment: It works. However, still I am not clear where I was wrong in manifest file. Also, I am registering it through my mainActivity(which is the first one to show up), after I close the activity, when application is completely closed, it no longer listens to this broadcast.

Comment: @harshit if you need it to work after activity was closed, you can use Service

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this permission in your manifest android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS?

This is basic, but just make sure