# How can I create timer tick in Android?

Tags: android

I have this method

```
public void GetSMS(){
       //in this method I read SMS in my app inbox,
       //If have new SMS create notification
}
```

for this I think create timer tick method and every 5 sec call GetSMS()

How can I create a correct method for that ?

Comment: Did you google for "timer in android"?

Comment: A handler can do that but you should read about BroadcastReceiver instead...

Comment: you are seriously considering polling the sms inbox every 5 seconds to know if there is a new message ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is an example of Timer and Timer Task. Hope this helps.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer timer = new Timer(false);
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do whatever you want
            }
        });
    }
};
timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000); // 1000 = 1 second.
```

Comment: :I called my receiveMessage method inside of the run() block but it does not being invoked every 1 second!would you please help me on this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe with a timer and a timertask?

See javadocs:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Yet receiving broadcasts is probably a more solid solution.
See: [Android - SMS Broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver)

Answer (score 5):

Use [Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)) as follow:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer timer = new Timer(false);
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GetSMS();
            }
        });
    }
};

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 5000, 5000); // every 5 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw it by accident.. This is not the right way to do it..

You don't need to check if there is a sms that received. Android provide broadcast receiver to get notified when sms is income.

Here you go, you have the link here.. Copy paste and it will work great

http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87

Hope that this make sense

Answer (score 1):

Although the above timer methods are the correct way to use timers of the sort you are after, I quite like this little hack:

```
new CountDownTimer(Long.MAX_VALUE, 5000)
{
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        // do something every 5 seconds...
    }

    public void onFinish()
    {
       // finish off when we're all dead !
    }
}.start();
```

`Long.MAX_VALUE` has, according the Java docs, a (signed) value of `2^63-1`, which is around 292471 millennia ! So starting up one of these countdown timers effectively lasts forever relatively speaking. Of course this depends on your interval time. If you want a timer every 1 second the timer would "only" last 58494 millenia, but we don't need to worry about that in the grander scheme of things.