# How to open an app from SMS

Tags: android, sms

Is there any possibility to open an `Activity` via `Intent` from SMS? Can I use `autoLink` and somehow override URL autolink to open my application or the GooglePlay page?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver) that scans incoming SMS for keywords, or check if the sender is a particular number.

If any of your checks match up, you can launch an Activity through an Intent.

However, keep in mind that users probably won't like it much if you opened up an Activity everytime they got an SMS. In most cases, you actually should use a notification.