# SMS Receiver not firing

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am having issues getting my broadcast receiver to fire. My code is as follows:

```
<receiver android:name="com.test.android.receivers.SMS" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>




public class SMS extends BroadcastReceiver {
private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage messages = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
    Logger.sendLog(TAG, messages.getOriginatingAddress());
}

}
```

The device is a HTC One X running a fresh version of CM.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.android.UIMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.android.UISettings"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_uisettings" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".services.LocService" >
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="com.test.android.receivers.SMS" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use READ_SMS permission into your Manifest before having at least 1 chance to intercept your SMSes.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />  and RECEIVE_SMS have been added with no difference.

Comment: Have you tried to read old reference on SO about BroadcastReceiver class? I've found many question about people struggling with this class. Try this for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your android manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

This line goes directly under the `<manifest>` tag, as follows:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <application ...>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Update**

I found This in the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml) of the default android mms application:

```
<!-- Require sender permissions to prevent SMS spoofing -->
<receiver android:name=".transaction.PrivilegedSmsReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The comment on the block gives me the impression that you need to acquire the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />` too.

Try it and let me know if that worked.

Comment: As mentioned in another comment, this is already the case with my application.

Comment: in the `<application>` do you have the attribute `android:enabled` set to false?. if so, your receiver will be disabled too. which means, the system will not be able to call your receiver.

Comment: I've added my manifest for viewing. I do not have enabled set to false.

Comment: I updated my answer. I don't know if this will help. but, you won't loose any if you tried :) .. let me know if it worked!

Answer (score 0):

set `android:exported="true"` inside your receiver tag. This will make your receiver available to other application. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestReceiver) out for more info.

So your final code should look like,

```
<receiver android:name="com.test.android.receivers.SMS" 
          android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter

               android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I think this should solve your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the issue. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Sorry I have written a wrong code. See the edited one. Tell me if this doesn't work.

Comment: `android:exported` is set to `true` by default if you provided an `<intent-filter>` in your declaration. so, it actually is `true` here without saying it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that.Sorry for this answer I thought it is always false regardless of <intent-filter>. I am wrong