# display android TOAST on receive of sms

Tags: android

i am working on an app which shows a toast on sms is received.i want either sms content to be displayed or just an notification that sms has been received.
I am using android studio. and am new to it. please help..

[image: Manifest file]
[image: SmsReceiver.java]

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: NO..all works fine. but no toast displayed

Comment: i am using telnet to send sms to my virtual device.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Just add a break point inside onReceive() method and check if broadcast receiver is called or not.

Comment: ya i rectified the code and now it shows the toast "SMS RECEIVED". now what i shud do to display the sms content in that toast ?

Comment: this app is working on my android emulator but it does not work on mobile. i hav tasted on kitkat , lolipop. and emulator i use is API19.

Answer (score 0):

Register a receiver which listens to new message. 
Refer these link
[Android - SMS Broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver)
and Blog : [Incomming SMS Broadcast Receiver - Android Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver)

Comment: i already did it i guess. in my Manifest.xml file. right sir !

Answer (score 0):

Use the `BroadcastReceiver` to listen to the sms received. 
Codes are here:

```
public class SmsReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage msg = null;
    if (null != bundle) {
        Object[] smsObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        for (Object object : smsObj) {
            msg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) object);
        Date date = new Date(msg.getTimestampMillis());//时间
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String receiveTime = format.format(date);
            Toast.make(context, "number:" + msg.getOriginatingAddress()
            + "   body:" + msg.getDisplayMessageBody() + "  time:"
                    + msg.getTimestampMillis(), 1000).show();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Meanwhile, add this in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
...
<receiver android:name="com.dbjtech.acbxt.waiqin.SmsReciver" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: no. still it is not showing. i edited my code as u hav posted. still no success.

Comment: but it works only on emulator. on mobile its is not working. i hav set target-sdk to 21 and min-sdk to 4. still it is not working on lolipop. by=ut work on API 19 android emulator

Answer (score 0):

If your app is running on an Android version > 3.0, you'll have to include an `Activity` that the user can start manually after installation to bring the app out of its *stopped state*, a [concept introduced in Android 3.1](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols). The system will not broadcast to *stopped* apps, so your `BroadcastReceiver` won't work until the app has been explicitly launched by the user.

Apart from that, your code appears to be correct.

Comment: it is working on android api19 emulator. but not on lolipop emulator