# app weather android using sms where internet connection is down to retrieve data from a server

Tags: android, sms, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm currently working on an android app weather that will retrieve data from a server where internet connection is set and will be using SMS to get data from the server where internet connection is down. How can i do that ?
the first part works perfectly. I have a struggle on getting data via sms.

Comment: You can use `BroadcastReceiver` to watch for incoming SMS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver.

Comment: You can send SMS though Email using a [SMS gateway protocol.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway) - This does however require you to know the carrier the device is on. What language are you writing your server in?

Comment: I'm using an existing free weather server online, and i'm asked to develop the client part. thank you