# Listen for incoming SMS messages even if the app is deleted from memory

Tags: android

I am trying to create a Broadcast receiver which receives incoming text message even when the app is deleted from the memory.

How can I do that? My Broadcast receiver is working fine when the app is in memory but it is not working if the memory is cleared!

Comment: can you add some try, so we can continue on

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android - SMS Broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver)

Comment: You can use service for that however it's not guaranteed to work because some device manufactures automatically delete service when app is killed

Comment: This solution does not work for Oreo or higher version.