# Custom scheme in SMS text

Tags: android, url, url-scheme

I've implemented a custom url scheme.  It works fine if I use the scheme in an  tag in html, but I want to send it in a text/plain SMS message.  The scheme does not get parsed by any of the standard apps.  Is there any way I can persuade apps to parse my new scheme to a link from plain text?

The scheme is "appname://go/something"

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is that this isn't possible.  We ended up using an http: link instead

Answer (score 3):

I've looked into this.

The only solution is to declare "android.permission.READ_SMS" in your manifest and  register a receiver to process SMS messages as they come in and parse for your custom scheme.

There is a good example of that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944102/android-sms-receiver-not-working)

That being said, please also see the response by @hackbod to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app/3472228) in which she makes it clear that custom scheme's should be avoided.

Comment: That wasn't really my point. I wanted apps that show SMSs to "linkify" the urls when they show them.  But it seems there is no universal registry of valid schemes in android.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [tapstream](https://tapstream.com/)  / deeplink.me to do that.. it will also redirect the user to the relevant app store if he doesn't have the app installed.
That's what we are doing in [paybox](http://payboxapp.com) and it works great