# Read an incomming SMS in Android

Tags: android, sms

I've got a BroadcastReceiver in my app:

```java
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 

   public void onCreate(){
        Log.i("APP","SMS Receiver started.");
   }

   @Override 
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
           Log.i("APP", "SMS received.");
       }
   }
```

And the receiver:

```xml
<receiver class="SMSReceiver" android:name=".SMSReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="smsreceiver" android:value="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

I start it with:

```java
Intent SMS = new Intent(this, SMSReceiver.class);
sendBroadcast(SMS);
```

In the main activity.

How can I read the content of the messages? Thanks.

Comment: Refer ! Refer! Refer!.

Check here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944102/android-sms-receiver-not-working

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare this in your mainfest:

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver"> 
        <intent-filter android:priority="100"> 
            <action android:name=
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

No need to start your receiver from intent when you declare it in manifest, it is automatically called when incoming message arrives.

And here is code for broadcast receiver:

**Put this code in your onRecieve method**

```
 if (!intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) 
                       return;          
                        bundle = intent.getExtras();

            if (bundle != null) {
                // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                // Set<String> Bundle.keySet();
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                // DeleteSMSFromInbox(context, msgs);
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {

                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    ClsIncomingsmsNo = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    System.out.println("ClsIncomingsmsNo" + ClsIncomingsmsNo);
                    msg = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();

}
```

}

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation of your code? Also make sure the brackets balance! I'm not sure if it was originally like that or got messed up somewhere, but it definitely could use fixing and you are best placed to do that because it's your code.