# Unable to instantiate receiver in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, sms, broadcastreceiver, instantiationexception

This is my first effort in making an Android app. It is a simple SMS listener that then displays SMS as a Toast.

```
public class SmsReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

String msgBody = null;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECIEVED")){
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msg = null;
        String msg_from;
        if(bundle != null)
        {
            try{
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msg = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for(int i=0;i<msg.length;i++)
            {
                msg[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                msg_from = msg[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                msgBody += msg[i].getMessageBody();
            }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, msgBody, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.droid.SmsReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.droid.SmsReceiver
```

I assure you the SmsReciever.java is in droid/src. I have spent whole night researching on this problem. Please help.

EDIT: This is the manifest xml file that u asked for.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" /> 

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
    <activity
        android:name=".JarvisActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_jarvis" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecureMessagesActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

EDIT: I did a bit of a research and found out that in my manifest file i have an activity tag which points to **SecureMessagesActivity**. But in my whole project i don't have an activity by that name. So is this the problem?

EDIT: Okay, So i deleted the SecureMessageActivity part from my manifest file and i guess it removed the error. Now i'm getting this Permisssion denial message:

```
Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED  flg=0x10 (has extras) } to net.learn2develop.SMSMessaging requires android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS due to sender com.android.phone (uid 1001)
```

Also **net.learn2develop.SMSMessaging** activity was used by me in an attempt to copy another code for the same purpose but now i have deleted the whole project and cleaned my own project many times. Still this activity keeps coming again and again.
**edit**
Chuck it i'll be starting all over again soon... Thanks for all the input.

Comment: Nopes dude... Tried everything...

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your receiver in your Adnroid manifest? If yes, please provide AndroidManifest.xml too. You may also want to check these related questions: [Android - SMS Broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver), [Android SMS receiver not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944102/android-sms-receiver-not-working), [BroadcastReceiver + SMS_RECEIVED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973071/broadcastreceiver-sms-received).

**EDIT**:

Try to add `android:exported="true"` to your `BroadcastReceiver`. This receiver works for me:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You have now `android:exported="false"` that basically tells Android that your `BroadcastReceiver` cannot receive messages from sources outside your application. More about this tag here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html.

Comment: Hey i've added the manifest file. Can u please hav a look at it again?

Comment: Edited my answer. Change android:exported tag to "true". It should help.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your receiver like this in manifest :

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.droid.SmsReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Still getting the same error.. :( ... Can there be a problem with my Eclipse software or the SDK i installed... I really getting helpless here.

Comment: i also implemented such thing. whatever you provided code is perfect. try to clean your project through eclipse. and then check.

Answer (score 0):

I have idea which can help you: lets try this code:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.droid.SmsReceiver" 
        android:exported="true" 
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.GSM_SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED2" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:host="localhost" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Different types of devices can use its own action name which is not a standard.