# Android Broadcast SMS receiver won't launch

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to build an app, which emails a picture after an sms is sent to the phone. So I have been following [this Tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87) with no success. When sending an sms to a real phone in debug mode, nothing happens. I've been trying to debug the app but the broadcastreceiver doesn't even launch.

```
public class SmsReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Log.i(TAG, "started…");
final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    try {
        if (bundle != null) {
            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Log.i("SmsReciever", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message" + message);

                //action

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception sms Reciever" + e);
    }
```

The Logcat does not print any errors or logs of that code bit. My manifest file looks like so:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tapplic.adrianopaulus.smscamera" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver android:name=".SmsReciever" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECIEVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I have also looked at these problems on stackoverflow:
[Android - SMS Broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver) 
[Android SMS reciever not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944102/android-sms-receiver-not-working/1944935#1944935)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permission strings are **case-sensitive**. You have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

You should have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

---

**EDIT: Add additional problem description:**

Also, the ACTION in your `<intent-filter>` is misspelled. You have:

```
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECIEVED" />
```

However, this should be:

```
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
```

The rule in English is "I before E, except after C" :-)

Comment: I tried it out but it didn't change anything, thanks thow

Comment: Have you run your Activity after installing the app? If you never launch your activity then your BroadcastReceiver will never be executed

Comment: Yes my camera which is my activity is running. But when I send a sms to that device nothing happens